# Why does my code or Serial Monitor hang with analogRead?

Tags: serial, analogread

I have the following code in loop() to collect values from an electret microphone

```
for(int i=0; i<sampleSize; i++){
  analogVal[i]= analogRead(ADC_Pin);
  sumOfSquares= sumOfSquares+sq(analogVal[i]);
}
Serial.print("Sum of squares: ");
Serial.print(sumOfSquares);
```

where sampleSize is an int variable, I've tried numbers from 3 to 1000, which is my desired value. ADC_Pin is an int variable set to be A1 and has been properly initialized through pinMode. analogVal is an int array of size sampleSize.

My circuit appears to be fine because the output produces a reasonable amount of voltage. I've tried eliminating the line with sumOfSquares and just having the first line in the for loop. However, the Serial Monitor hangs and does not display any values. The serial communication is at 9600 bps.

Comment: You claim  “the Serial Monitor hangs and does not display any values” even though the code doesn't have any references to Serial output!  Obviously that's the problem! ¶ Please edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code, not just snippets.

Comment: I've added the serial prints that immediately follow the for loop. It does not matter whether the Serial.print is inside or outside the for loop. The serial monitor does not show anything.

Comment: Now the obvious problem is that you didn't say `Serial.begin(115200);` [or whatever the data rate is that you have your serial monitor set at] ¶ Anyway, I don't know what the problem is, and if you don't edit your question to include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of code -- with visible definitions of every variable used, etc -- perhaps nobody else will be able to tell either.

Comment: Yes, MCVE please. There's nothing wrong with the code in your question which would result in this particular problem. (There's another problem but never mind that for now.) The problem is with code you haven't shown.

Comment: What is `analogVal`? What is `sumOfSquares`? What is the `sq()` function? In short: **DO NOT POST SNIPPETS LIKE THIS - POST A COMPLETE PROGRAM SO WE CAN SEE THE ENTIRE PROGRAM AND VARIABLE DECLARATIONS.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arduino UNO have 2K RAM (many other too). That is 2048 bytes of RAM.

I suppose, that `analogVals[]` is declared as `int` and having 1000 entries it takes 2000 bytes of RAM, leaving wholesome `48 bytes` for all your others variables (including `int i` in the for cycle and `Serial` outside it) and stack for calling functions (like `analogRead` and `sq`) and all theirs variables and functions and arguments.

So `int i` = 2B, `Serial` = 2B, `sumOfSquares` = 2B, `"Sum of squares: "` = 17B of what I see takes anothe `23 bytes` of those `48 bytes` leaving us with only **25 bytes** for all else.

I bet, that you try to use more REAM, than you have and so your `stack overflows` and

1. destroys some variable content on the vay
2. is overwriten by assigning to some variables, which then leads to all sort of problems.